# Nine cards $1$ to $9$, drawn twice simultaneously , whats the expected value of the score?

Tags: probability

Nine cards $1$ to $9$, drawn twice simultaneously, $S$ denote sum of $2$ numbers drawn. $S \leq 5$ the score is $10-S$, and when the $S>5$ the score is $2$. whats the expected value of the score?

I don't understand the questions "whats the expected value of the score?" so, I can't solve it, so far I found the probability of getting the sum $S\leq 5$ that is $1/9$.

Comment: You have a random variable, $X$ which represents the score.  There are only finitely many values $X$ can take and it takes each value with some probability.  You are asked to find the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of that variable.

Comment: ok thanks @lulu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\dbinom92=36$ possible draws. Of these, only $4$ have $S\le5$, namely $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)$, scoring $7,6,5,5$ respectively. Everything else ($32$ draws) scores $2$.

The expected value is the average value, and is:

$$\frac{7+6+5+5+32\cdot2}{36}$$
$$=\frac{87}{36}=\frac{29}{12}=2\frac{5}{12}$$